# How to set GIF file as Wallpaper in Android Programatically

Tags: android

I do many R&D but does not get proper answer and still finding but didn't get the answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Share some of your R&D (Research and Development) here.

Answer (score 1):

This view class can help you to set GIF file

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;



public class GIFView extends View {
public Movie mMovie;
public long movieStart;

public GIFView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initializeView();
}

public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initializeView();
}

public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initializeView();
}

private void initializeView() {
    InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.animated);
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    if (movieStart == 0) {
        movieStart = now;
    }
    if (mMovie != null) {
        int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % mMovie.duration());
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(), getHeight() - mMovie.height());
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
private int gifId;

public void setGIFResource(int resId) {
    this.gifId = resId;
    initializeView();
}

public int getGIFResource() {
    return this.gifId;
}
}
```

in your xml file use this like that:

```
<com.example.YourPakageName.GIFView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
components:src="@drawable/animated" />
```